# SQL Server Select Record based on datetime and user type

Tags: sql-server

```
     id|   type   |  datetime    |
    ---| ---------|--------------|
     1 | admin    | 2016-01-03   |
     2 | user     | 2016-01-07   |
     3 | user     | 2016-01-08   |
     4 | admin    | 2016-01-04   |
     5 | user     | 2016-01-01   |
     6 | user     | 2016-01-03   |
     7 | user     | 2016-01-05   |
     8 | user     | 2016-01-09   |
```

Lets say I have a table above and I need to rearrange it based on the datetime. The first record must from admin with the latest datetime among the type of admin only. Then the second to fifth record must from the type of user sort by their datetime descending. Then again, the sixth record must from type of admin with the second latest datetime. The expected result from the query is shown in the table below.

Expected Result:

```
     id|   type   |  datetime    |
    ---| ---------|--------------|
     4 | admin    | 2016-01-04   |
     8 | user     | 2016-01-09   |
     3 | user     | 2016-01-08   |        
     2 | user     | 2016-01-07   |
     1 | admin    | 2016-01-03   |
     7 | user     | 2016-01-05   |
     6 | user     | 2016-01-03   |
     5 | user     | 2016-01-01   |
```

Can you guys give me some idea on how to write the query to get the expected result?

Comment: does this a continues thing or just these 9 rows ?

Comment: This is a very unusual request, can you tell us why you would want to do that? It is also not clear what you have already tried.

Comment: Ya,it's a continues thing. These 9 rows are just example only.

Comment: @NamelessOne Actually i already to select by using 2 queries and use two php for loop to display the data. But this will affect the performance, it takes time to load. So, i am wonder is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: What you need is always admin followed by 3 users, both sorted independently? Does that make sense? You said "second to fifth" but in your example you did second to fourth.

Comment: @Andrew ya, the order is always start with admin followed by 3 users and sorted independently.

Comment: May I ask why do you want this? It doesn't seem to make sense and maybe there's a better alternative. What's your final goal?

Comment: @Andrew Based on the requirement of the project, I need to display to selected results in this order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it without the issues of `NTILE` when your count is not exactly divisible by the amount of users you want to group. Based on gofr1's script, this is what I suggest you use:

```
SELECT  id,
        [type],
        [datetime]
FROM (
    SELECT  id,
            [type],
            [datetime],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [datetime]) - 1 Idx
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [type] = 'admin'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  id,
            [type],
            [datetime],
            FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [datetime]) - 1) / 3) Idx
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [type] = 'user'
    ) as p
ORDER BY Idx, [type]
```

Comment: Wow, it's working too, your code is more easy to understand compare to @gofr1 code, thank you for your effort. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually with NTILE you will get different results depending on your count. For example, if you had 10 users, NTILE(2) would give 5-5, NTILE(3) would give you 4-3-3 and NTILE(4) would give you 3-3-2-2. No option would give you of 3-3-3-1.

Comment: Thank you guys, really appreciate the work of you two, your answer save me hours of work and research.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) in sample below it distributes the rows in 2 groups, and then you need just to order it by group number and datetime:

```
SELECT  id,
        [type],
        [datetime]
FROM (
    SELECT  id,
            [type],
            [datetime],
            NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY [datetime] DESC) as NT
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [type] = 'admin' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  id,
            [type],
            [datetime],
            NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY [datetime] DESC) as NT
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [type] = 'user'
    ) as p
ORDER BY NT, [type]
```

Output:

```
id  type    datetime
4   admin   2016-01-04
8   user    2016-01-09
3   user    2016-01-08
2   user    2016-01-07
1   admin   2016-01-03
7   user    2016-01-05
6   user    2016-01-03
5   user    2016-01-01
```

Note: if you need dynamically determine the groups number (f.e. based on rows count) you can use this:

```
DECLARE @i int

SELECT @i = --some number

NTILE(@i) OVER (ORDER BY ...
```

I advice to use:

```
SELECT @i = CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*)%4.00 = 1 THEN ROUND(COUNT(*)/4.00,0)+1 ELSE ROUND(COUNT(*)/4.00,0) END as int)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Can i make it always start with admin then followed by 3 users?

Comment: And it is not? I checked on sample you provided and as you can see in output it orders it as you need.

Comment: Just now I had try to change the value in the NTILE, after that is working.. thanks you so much.

Comment: For @i, don't you have to divide the count of the group by the number of rows you want each time? And doesn't that gives you wrong results because of rounding? With `NTILE(2)` I get half of the admins, then half of the users, and then the second halves.

Comment: sorry one more question, i changed the NTILE to (8) then it is working, and it's only display until NT = 8, what if I have more data? Is it still working?

Comment: I bet your table will get larger, so you need to tie it to something. F.e. rows with  `[type] = 'admin'` : `SELECT @i = COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE [type] = 'admin'`

Comment: @gofr1, but what happens with the users? You have to divide that by 3, and that would only work if the count is divisible by 3. Otherwise, you will get 3 or 4 users between each admin.

Comment: @gofr1 can you give me another example with details?

Comment: @Andrew it is just an example. OP need some sort of count to get his table divided in groups dynamically. What if he will have only 10 users and 5 admins? How he will divide his table? The best way (I think) is to get count of all rows with type admin and user and divide it by 4.

Comment: @gofr1, as I said, it will fail unless the user count is exactly divisible by your number. In your last example, 10 / 4 = 2.5, rounded it's 2, so you will get 1 admin, 5 users, 1 admin, 5 users, 3 admins (this last part is unavoidable). If you do 10 / 3 = 3.33 => 3, you will get 1 admin, 4 users, 1 admin, 3 users, 1 admin, 3 users, 2 admins.

Comment: @JK9 I add some count sample you can try.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for you research. It is all matter of data in table. If we got 10 rows, 2 of them with admin and 10/4 = 3 than you will get 1 admin 3 users 1 admin 5 users

Comment: @gofr1, sorry to insist, you won't get a consistent result. If you have a different count, with NTILE(3) you may get 4 users.

Comment: @Andrew :) once again, there might be 10 admins and 10 users - how to dived them as OP wanted? If we got 1 admin and 100 users? It is a general approach and it is not perfect. If you have another vision on this problem, please, share it.

Comment: I just did. :) The problem is with `NTILE`. With 10 users, NTILE(2) will give 5-5, NTILE(3) will give you 4-3-3 and NTILE(4) will give you 3-3-2-2. No option will give you of 3-3-3-1.